# Does child process get access to pipe if execv() is used after fork()?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, exec, fork

I am aware that child process has exactly the same copy of the file descriptor table as the parent just before the fork() call. Suppose I open a pipe just before the fork() call,

```
pipe(fd[2*i]);
pipe(fd[2*i+1]);
pid = fork();
if(pid)
{
        strcpy(_args[0], "child");
        sprintf(_args[1], "%d", fd[2*i][0]);
        sprintf(_args[2], "%d", fd[2*i+1][1]);
        _args[4] = NULL;
        if(execv(_args[0], _args) == -1) printf("execv error\n");
}
```

Assuming child is my child process, is this a legal way of using the pipe across the parent and the child process? (This is an actual part of my code).

My program 'freezes' while execution, and when I use SIGTSTP, I get /sysdeps/nptl/fork.c - no such file or directory. Both the parent and the child are in the same directory. What is the problem here?

Comment: Is that *pseudo-code*? Because if you call [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) with `fd` and then use `fd` as an array of arrays that won't work very well.

Comment: You would usually also close the unused file descriptors in each process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg edited the code area. I blindly copied a part of my code, not realising it would create confusion.

Comment: I recommend you learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and do note that such an MCVE should contain the variable declarations (or it wouldn't be complete).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a part of the code, thus I can just guess. If you create a pipe, you always need a reader and a writer. In your sample we just see the writer.

What you typically do in the child is to connect it through pipes to the parent, overwriting its stdin/out. Close its stdin/out and dup() the pipes' fds, like this:

```
close(0);
dup(in);   // reading end of input pipe
close(in); // close unused fd
close(1);
dup(out);  // writing end of output pipe
close(out);// close unused fd
```

The other ends of these pipes are handled in the parent separately.

Comment: don't forget to close `in` and `out` after `dup` especially if they are pipe descriptors...